# How to use Python API to create an interactive parametric mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I want to add my custom mesh to Blender. I already know about vertices, edges, faces, `bpy.data.meshes`, etc, but I can't figure out how to create an interactive parametric mesh, just like Maya's primary object that can adjust the height or radius of the mesh on the fly.

[image]

UPDATE:

What shape is actually not important, it can be any shape that can be adjusted on the fly.

It can be a plane with only 3 vertices, like this:

```py
import bpy

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []

verts.append([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
faces.append([0,1,2])

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("New Mesh") 
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("New Object", mesh) 
col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection") 
col.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
```

Now I want to add a slider to control the position of the vertices, or change its shape or even the number of vertices. How to do that?

My goal is to create an addon that dynamically generates pie charts and adjusts them on the fly. This is what I did in Maya:

[image]

I know about the *Extra Objects* addon, but I also found out that it doesn't have a dynamic slider either. For example, for *Add > Mesh > Gear*, you can find some parameters, but you can't see the result in real-time. After changing the parameters, you have to right click > *Change Gear* to refresh the object.

That's why I wanted to make my own, dynamically adjustable object. Just like in Maya.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Oh so you already have your shape? What shape do you want to add? because Blender has already alot of shapes available with the [Extra Objects addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html#add-mesh-extra-objects) Please update your post to show what mesh you want to add. You can also see this answer for some idea https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298786/142292

Comment: *Add -> mesh -> gear", you can find some parameters, but you can't see the result in real-time.*. > No that is not correct, you can actually see the adjustments in real time like changing the number of teeth in the lower left corner of the *Add Gear* popup, just like in my gif i presented with the torus. Either you are doing it incorrectly or there is a problem with your blender. Please show a gif that demonstrates what you mean with the "*you can't see the result in real-time*"

Comment: here is the blender gear video: https://youtube.com/shorts/3BuReo0-1pw?feature=share

Comment: Oh, I found the bottom left panel and it works.
Wondering what the parameters in "Object Property -> Custom Properties" do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender already has several Polyhedrons you can choose from. For example if you enable the built-in [`Add Mesh: Extra Objects`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html#add-mesh-extra-objects) addon under menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*, you can add the Torus via menu *Add > Mesh > Torus* and you can also add several different [Parametric Surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface) using *Add > Mesh > Math Function*. You can add more objects from the [`Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/geodesic_domes.html). It's also possible to add these complex surfaces using [`Geometry Nodes`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html). See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270409/how-can-i-plot-this-cartesian-equation-in-geometry-nodes) and [that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260497/how-do-i-create-a-3d-parametric-surface-using-geometry-nodes).

[image]

If you want to add your own mesh, you can do it [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290624/not-able-to-create-a-mesh-from-data-in-obj-format-using-python-api/290627#290627) or you can use the [`bmesh`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) module. Here I have prepared a script which you can run in the [Text Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) which registers a new operator called `MyShapeOperator` that creates a simple Torus when you click *Run Script*, but you can create any shape with any editable properties. Then go to 3D View and press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search it. Now you can edit the example properties I have added using the [`Adjust Last Operation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) popup panel that appears in the lower left corner.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *
import math

class MyShapeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_shape"
    bl_label = "My Shape Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    radius_major : FloatProperty (
        name = "Major Radius",
        description = "This is the Major or Outer Radius",
        default = 2.0,
        min = 0.3,
        max = 10.0
    )

    radius_minor : FloatProperty (
        name = "Minor Radius",
        description = "This is the Minor or Inner Radius",
        default = 0.5,
        min = 0.4,
        max = 7.0
    )

    segments_major : IntProperty (
        name = "Major Segments",
        description = "This is Major Segments",
        default = 48,
        min = 4,
        max = 200
    )
    
    segments_minor : IntProperty (
        name = "Minor Segments",
        description = "This is Minor Segments",
        default = 12,
        min = 4,
        max = 200
    )

    def create_or_update_your_shape(self, context):
        location = (0, 0, 0)
        rotation = (0, 0, 0)

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(
            align='WORLD',
            major_radius=self.radius_major,
            minor_radius=self.radius_minor,
            major_segments=self.segments_major,
            minor_segments=self.segments_minor,
            location=location,
            rotation=rotation
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        self.create_or_update_your_shape(context)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyShapeOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyShapeOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Blender, a lot of info. I need to research for a while. Thanks.